# Clickable area's within image view?

Tags: android, xml, layout

I'm trying to make each area on this image clickable. I have cutting the image into its different selections and then put it together with a relative layout then used a onclick for each area. This works however the transparent area around the images count as the clickable area too. This makes some area's hard/impossible to click on.

Here is the image: http://i77.photobucket.com/albums/j59/jombobmerly/footProb.png

Is there any way to make the onlclick ignore the transparent area's or is this just not going to work?

Answer (score 0):

// you can use onTouch Listner

```
myimageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

   Log.e("HIGHT CLICk!!"+ event.getY(), "-----------"+event.getX());

    if((26<event.getX() && event.getX()<120) && (25<event.getY()&&event.getY()<120)){

//do your actions here
}
```

Comment: I understand that a onTouchListener could be used, however how would i used it on such complicated shapes as in my picture? http://i77.photobucket.com/albums/j59/jombobmerly/footProb.png

Comment: @JamieOsborn get the points using any image editor like gimp and place it in OnTouch as I mentioned above.